# C# Entity Overview Table of one to many checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can't seem to find how to build a proper solution for a one to many checkbox.

So what do i have :

I have an article and an admin user can set user rights to that article.
So in my article right page you have an overview with all the users.

My article:

```
public partial class Artikel
    {
        public Artikel()
        {
            this.ArtikelLinks = new HashSet<ArtikelLink>();
            this.ArtikelRights = new HashSet<ArtikelRight>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string naam { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArtikelLink> ArtikelLinks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ArtikelRight> ArtikelRights { get; set; }
    }
```

My rights class

```
 public partial class ArtikelRight
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public System.Guid userId { get; set; }
        public int artikelId { get; set; }
        public bool hasRight { get; set; }

        public virtual Artikel Artikel { get; set; }
    }
```

How do i build my view? i tried several ways but i can't seem to save my data.
this is my rights view at the moment:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <table width="90%" align="center" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th align="left">Gebruiker</th> 
                    <th align="left">Heeft toegang</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead> 
               @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.ArtikelRights, "ArtikelRight")
        </table>

        <br />
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" class="btn btn-sm beige" />
        </div>
}
```

And this is my partial Artikel right view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GtiProducts.Models.ArtikelRight>


@foreach (var item in Model) { 
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Membership.GetUser(item.userId).UserName
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => item.hasRight)

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My save action is:

```
public ActionResult Rights(Artikel art)
{

    repo.SaveChanges();
    return View(art);
}
```

When i debug my art.ArtikelRights is null.
How can i fix this and what's the best solution to do this with the entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the partial to make it an `EditorTemplate`- `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ArtikelRight.cshtml`, then make the following modifications

```
@model GtiProducts.Models.ArtikelRight // not IEnumerable
<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.hasRight)</td>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.hasRight, "....") // the users name?
    @Html.HiddenFor(m > m.id) // or what ever property you need to identify the ArtikelRight.cshtml
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then in the main view

```
<tbody>
  @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.ArtikelRights)
</tbody>
```

This will correctly name you controls with indexers so they can be bound to your model on post back, for example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ArtikelRights[0].hasRight" ...>
<input type="checkbox" name="ArtikelRights[1].hasRight" ...>
```

Side note: You should not be using `@Membership.GetUser(item.userId).UserName` in the view. Instead create a view model with only those properties you need in the view (which appears to be `id` and `hasright`, and include a property for the users display name (and populate it in the controller).